# Find an array based on value of a variable

Tags: jquery

I have the array

```
var login = ["login", "php"];
```

And the variable `withoutNumberSign` which is set based on the URL and should in this case be defined as `login`. I need to use the array based on the value of `withoutNumberSign`. How would I do that?

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to accomplish specifically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Gnarlywhale I need to use the array based on the value of withoutNumberSign. How would I do that?

Comment: Are you referring to selecting an array based on the string variable in `withoutNumberSign`?

Comment: Do you have multiple other arrays besides `login`?

Comment: @Gnarlywhale No, just the one. I haven't tried anything yet since I don't really know how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one solution I can see is to **eval** the value of **withoutNumberSign** and assign that to a new variable, which then you can use to dereference the array you want to use. So that would look like:

```
var login = ["login", "php"];
// This for testing
// var withoutNumberSign = "login";
var newvar = eval(withoutNumberSign);
console.log(newvar[0]);
```

A more elegant solution IMO would be to use an **associative array** at your first layer, on which you'd perform a lookup based on **withoutNumberSign**.

```
var associativeArray = {};
associativeArray["login"] = ["login", "php"];
console.log(associativeArray[withoutNumberSign][0]);
```

Comment: The associativeArray solution is a much cleaner implementation.

Comment: I used the associative array and it works perfectly! Thanks!